# How to use DependencyInjection from symfony in stand alone application with commands?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-console

I have been using symfony/console for making commands and registering them like that, everything works fine:

**bin/console:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Commands\LocalitiesCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$app = new Application();
$app->add(new LocalitiesCommand(new LocalitiesGenerator()));
$app->run();
```

**src/Commands/LocalitiesCommand.php:**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Commands;

use App\LocalitiesGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;


final class LocalitiesCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:generate-localities';

    public function __construct(private LocalitiesGenerator $localitiesGenerator)
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this
            ->setDescription('Generate localities.json file')
            ->setHelp('No arguments needed.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $this->localitiesGenerator->generateJsonLocalities();
        $output->writeln("File localities.json generated!");
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Now I want to autoinject the service with symfony/dependency-injection, I was reading the documentation and did some changes:

new **bin/console:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Commands\LocalitiesCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/src/config'));
$loader->load('services.yaml');
$container->compile();


$app = new Application();
$app->add(new LocalitiesCommand());
$app->run();
```

**config/services.yaml:**

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false
```

But still asks me to add my service in the constructor when I instantiate my command. Why is it not working?

Comment: are you using composer ?

Comment: @RudyDavid yes i'm using composer

Comment: @yivi It is possible I saw some tutorials and also symfony allows inject services in to commands, you can check it here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container

Comment: @yivi Aah now I understand what you mean sorry, anything I can read to achieve what I want or any documentation you know?

Comment: Changing $app->add(new LocalitiesCommand()); to $app->add($container->get(LocalitiesCommand::class); and making your services public might do the trick.  But quite honestly once you start using the container in these sorts of things then just using the symfony/skeleton app makes more sense.  I am also assuming you only showed part of your services.yaml file.   You obviously need to actually scan the directories or at least add your command as a service.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, let's clear up a misconception:

> But still asks me to add my service in the constructor when I instantiate my command. Why is it not working?

If you call `new Foo()`, then you no longer are getting autowired DI benefits. If you want to use autowire and automatic dependency injection, you need to let Symfony work for you. When you call `new`, you are instantiating the object manually, and you need to take care of DI on your own.

With that out of the way, how would you get to do this?

---

First, `composer.json` with the basic dependencies and autoloader declaration:

The full directory structure will end up being like this:

```
<project_dir>
├── composer.json 
├── app 
├── src/
│    ├── ConsoleCommand/
│    │       └── FooCommand.php
│    └── Text/
│          └── Reverser.php
├── config/
│    ├── services.yaml
```

Now, each of the parts:

The `composer.json` file with all the dependencies and autoloader:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^5.3",
        "symfony/console": "^5.3",
        "symfony/config": "^5.3",
        "symfony/yaml": "^5.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

The front-controller script, the file running the application (`app`, in my case):

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use Symfony\Component;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

class App extends Component\Console\Application
{

    public function __construct(iterable $commands)
    {
        $commands = $commands instanceof Traversable ? iterator_to_array($commands) : $commands;

        foreach ($commands as $command) {
            $this->add($command);
        }

        parent::__construct();
    }
}

$container = new Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder();
$loader    = new Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new Component\Config\FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/config'));

$loader->load('services.yaml');
$container->compile();

$app = $container->get(App::class);
$app->run();
```

The service container configuration for the project:

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true

  _instanceof:
    Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command:
      tags: [ 'app.command' ]

  App\:
    resource: '../src/*'

  App:
    class: \App
    public: true
    arguments:
      - !tagged_iterator app.command
```

One `FooCommand` class:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

// src/ConsoleCommand/FooCommand.php

namespace App\ConsoleCommand;

use App\Text\Reverser;
use Symfony\Component\Console;

class FooCommand extends Console\Command\Command
{

    protected static $defaultName = 'foo';

    public function __construct(private Reverser $reverser)
    {
        parent::__construct(self::$defaultName);
    }

    protected function execute(Console\Input\InputInterface $input, Console\Output\OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $output->writeln('Foo was invoked');
        $output->writeln($this->reverser->exec('the lazy fox'));

        return self::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

The above depends on the `App\Text\Reverser` service, which will be injected automatically for us by the DI component:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Text;

class Reverser
{

    public function exec(string $in): string
    {
        return \strrev($in);
    }
}
```

After installing and dumping the autoloader, by executing `php app` (1) I get that the `foo` command is available (2):
[image]

I can execute `php app foo`, and the command is executed correctly, using its injected dependencies:

[image]

A self-contained Symfony Console application, with minimal dependencies and automatic dependency injection.

(All the code for a very similar example, [here](https://github.com/yivi/standalone_symfony_console)).

Comment: I have built a similar solution to that one, only difference I left the `services.yaml` only for App related services configuration. Also includes DotEnv. I just pushed it to github and it's available at packagist https://packagist.org/packages/coral-media/crune

Comment: Got the idea from https://carlalexander.ca/symfony-console-application-autowire/

Answer (score 0):

No crazy setup required, just add your commands as `CliApplication` dependencies and register them in constructor:

```
class MyCliApplication extends Application
{

    public function __construct(
        FindSocksCommand $findSocks,
        FindPantsCommand $findPants
    )
    {
        parent::__construct('td2ac CLI');
        $this->addCommands(
            [
                $findSocks,
                $findPants
            ]
        );
    }


}

$app = $container->get(MyCliApplication::class);
$app->run();
```